# How to add Custom button in full calendar implemented in angular2 Application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I found the link to add custom button in full calender:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/

But i have implementing full calender in Angular2 Application. so need the logic to add custom button using type script in angular2 app.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

add the custom button to options in .ts file

```
options = {
    customButtons: {
      myCustomButton: {
        text: 'custom!',
      }
    }
  };
```

.html

```
<p-schedule #cal [events]="events"
                 [header]="header"
                 [options]="options">
</p-schedule>
```